# Duplicação de código no Laravel ORM

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Eu estava trabalhando e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```
if (($entrada == null) and ($parcela == null)) {
    $cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))
        ->get();
} elseif ($parcela == null) {
    $cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))
        ->where('entrada', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $entrada))
        ->get();
} elseif ($entrada == null) {
    $cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))
        ->whereHas('saldo', function ($query) use ($parcela, $porcentagem) {
            $query->where('parcela', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $parcela));
        })
        ->get();
} else {
    $cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))
        ->where('entrada', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $entrada))
        ->whereHas('saldo', function ($query) use ($parcela, $porcentagem) {
            $query->where('parcela', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $parcela));
        })
        ->get();
}

return $cotas;
```

Existe uma maneira mais elegante de criar essa função? Que eu não repita tanto o código, pensei em usar SQL puro e ir concatenando as instruções, seria uma implementação melhor... lembrando que sou iniciante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se você notar vai ver que existem algumas linhas que se repetem sempre em todas as condições como:

```
Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))

Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito);

function($query) use ($parcela, porcentagem) {
    $query->where('parcela', '<=', $porcentagem);
}
```

Sabendo disso você pode move-las para fora de cada `if` e adicionar nas condições apenas uma variável que resume a ação, veja;

```
$cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
    ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
    ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
    ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito))

$porcentagem = Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito);

$parcelaQuery = function($query) use ($parcela, porcentagem) {
    $query->where('parcela', '<=', $porcentagem);
}


// você pode usar o operador ! para inverter a condição
if (!$entrada and !$parcela) {
    $cotas->where('credito', '<=', $porcentagem);
} else if (!$parcela) {
    $cotas->where('entrada', '<=', $porcentagem);
} else if (!$entrada) {
    $cotas->whereHas('saldo', $parcelaQuery);
} else {
    $cotas->where('entrada', '<=', $porcentagem)->whereHas('saldo', $parcelaQuery)
}

return $cotas->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$calculaPorcentagem = Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito);

$query = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', $calculaPorcentagem);

if (is_null($entrada) and is_null($parcela))
    return $query->get();

if (is_null($parcela)) 
    return $query->where('entrada', '<=', $calculaPorcentagem)->get();

$query = is_null($entrada) ? $query : $query->where('entrada', '<=', $calculaPorcentagem);

return $query->whereHas('saldo', function ($query) {
            $query->where('parcela', '<=', $calculaPorcentagem);
        })->get();
```

Assim você coloca em uma variável e pode reaproveitar nos próximos passos.

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de refatorar o codigo e aplicar uma das duas respostas do post eu percebi que dava pra fazer algo um pouco diferente, usando do que aprendi com as respostas do Wictor e do RFL, valeu pessoal as respostas foram muito esclarecedoras:

```
$cotas = Produto::orderBy('credito', 'DESC')
        ->where('id_subcategoria', $subcategoria)
        ->where('visivel_site', self::SIM)
        ->where('credito', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $credito));

    if (isset($entrada)) {
        $cotas = $cotas
            ->where('entrada', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $entrada));
    }
    if (isset($parcela)) {
        $cotas = $cotas
            ->whereHas('saldo', function ($newquery) use ($parcela, $porcentagem) {
                $newquery->where('parcela', '<=', Utils::calculaPorcentagem($porcentagem, $parcela));
            });
    }

    return $cotas->get();
```